# New page for every paragraph

Tags: formatting

For proof-reading-purposes I would like Latex to begin every separate paragraph on a new page. Is it possible to redefine \par or issue a command to achieve this?

Example paragraphs:

````
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.```
````

Comment: Are your paragraphs ended by \\ command? Or are your new paragraphs started with \par commands?

Comment: I''m thinking about normal paragraphs separated with linebreaks.

Comment: Yes, but in your .tex file how are paragraphs separated? Have you made one .tex file?

Comment: I have one .tex file and the paragraphs are separated by pressing enter twice.

Comment: In the log files, blank lines are replaced by \par, so it is possible redefining \par might work.  \everypar{\newpage} will work until it gets redefined by some;thing else (like \@afterheading).

Comment: @Niranjan you can not separate paragraphs with `\\ `

Comment: @Fran ah. the answer there looks similar:-) I'll close..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know that command is for linebreak, but people also tend to end a line first and then start a new par. I myself do this. So I thought it would have been easier to redefine \\

Comment: @Niranjan that is an error latex will warn you about the resulting bad output

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

````
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\parskip{\textheight}
\begin{document}

sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  Ut enim
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.```

sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  Ut enim
ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.```

\end{document}
````

Comment: Thank you. Just what I was trying to accomplish!

Comment: That's cheating! (In a good way)